# Previewing .msg files within a .zip file

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, windows-explorer, pdf, zip

In Windows 10 with Acrobat 11 and Outlook 2013 installed, I am able to preview .pdf files and .msg files in the preview pane of Explorer.

However, when I open a .zip file in Explorer (using Win10's native .zip handling) I am able to preview .pdfs normally, however nothing else will show up in preview (I've tried .txt, .jpg and .msg). Instead it says "no preview available". I assumed it was a permissions issue but the temp folder for .zip files seems to have the right permissions for any program to access it.

What wizardry is the "Adobe PDF Preview Handler for Vista" doing that allows it to preview from within a .zip file? And how could I extend that to other preview handlers, especially for Outlook? I've tried assigning .msg files to various email preview handlers, HTML & MAPI, without any luck using the Preview Handler Editor.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you need a preview handler for .zip files.

Comment: According to my tests in my windows 10, seems that I have the same condition as you: could successfully preview .pdf files and .msg files in the preview pane of Explorer but not be able to preview when open a .zip file in Explorer. We might need a preview handler which could support  .zip files. However, could not found more inforamtion other than the Preview Handler Editor you mentioned. Similar thread for your reference: https://superuser.com/questions/548470/windows-7-explorer-preview-pane-for-zip-files